# C# How do I check a selected item in a listbox using code?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a listbox with checkboxes, how do I check the checkbox of the selecteditem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Windows Forms, clb.SetItemChecked(clb.SelectedIndex,true) where clb is a CheckedListBox object.